# Storing string-to-int dictionary with tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm using Tensorflow to perform online learning and classification where the number of classes is not specified in advance i.e. the model has to support adding and removing classes in an online fashion. Furthermore, I plan to maintain a dictionary of class names (string) to corresponding indices in the output layer. This dictionary will be updated every time a class is added or deleted.

Is there any way to store this dynamic dictionary with the tensorflow graph? I have looked at [lookup_ops in tensorflow](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/contrib/lookup/lookup_ops.py), but they do not support operations for adding or deleting classes.

Answer (score 0):

How about storing names in a 1d variable of string type, and use a second 1d variable of int type to store corresponding indices? This would have O(n) lookup time; might suffice if the number of classes is small though.